# Create Table showing Foldername and Count of files

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that, based on a list of directories, produces a list or table showing 'Folder Name' and 'Count' of files contained within each folder.

I have the following so far:

```
$folders = @("c:\temp", "C:\temp\tosh")

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File
    $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Folder = $folder
        Count = $folderFiles.count
    }
    $obj | Format-Table
}
```

This works but produces effectively two tables, one for each folder.  I need this as one table but when I try to add another row to the object I get an error that `PSObject does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'`.  I'm sure that I've had a similar result before by adding the `$obj` object to an array at each iteration similar to this:

```
$results += $obj
```

But can't seem to get it working at present.  Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `$results` first as type `array` and then you can add values to the array. If you don't do so, then `$results` will be `System.Object` `BaseType` and hence the error. Try this.

```
$folders = @("c:\temp", "C:\temp\tosh")
$results = @()
foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    $folderFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File
    $obj = New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Folder = $folder
        Count = $folderFiles.count
    }
    $results += $obj
}
$results
```

Comment: Grr, my bad! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

[Vivek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48519536/5039142) will get you what you're after.

You can simply this further, avoiding the need to initialise an empty array and to use a temporary object. This uses the pscsutomobject type accelerator.

```
$folders = @("c:\temp", "C:\temp\tosh")

foreach ($folder in $folders) {
    [array]$results += [pscustomobject]@{
        Folder = $folder
        Count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File).count
    }
}
$results
```

I see that you have`$obj | Format-Table` in your loop. You could have `$results | Format-Table` at the end instead.

Answer (score 0):

ls \temp,\temp\tosh\ | group psparentpath | select count,name